# Remove white space picture thumbnail

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

How to remove the white space when I have landscape images and portrait? Instead of having a white space I want the images to move up and fill that white space, I know it will not look aligned but thats ok.

Also I would like the images to resize depending on the browser window scale.

HTML:

```
<?php
$dir = "img/";
$img = glob($dir . "*.jpg");

foreach ($img as $image) {
  echo "<img src='$image' class='imageCont'/>";
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Photography</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
.imageCont {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 1px;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.imageCont:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 47px -2px #000000bf;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
```

[image: How it looks now]

Comment: What happens if you add `float: left` / `margin: 0` your images?

Comment: you need to use a [masonry js plugin](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=js+masonry) by the looks of things.  Also, move the echo to within the body of your html - if you echo them at the top like that, your html is invalid

Comment: Can you add html rendered code?

Comment: You need to organize the images into columns. Also, you need to move that `foreach` loop into your `<body>` in order to create valid HTML.

Comment: Pete thanks i will look into Masonry looks promising

Answer (score 0):

To move the images up, you will need to align them, and for that you need to use

```
vertical-align:top;
```

To remove the left/right space, indeed you will need to use:

```
float:left;
```

Or

```
margin-left:-3px;
```

Have in mind the fact that if the height of the rows is different, the images of next row  will align at the bottom of the biggest image of the previous one.

Comment: tried that it did worked for half of the images, but for some reason the rest was not working properly

Answer (score 0):

I found a different way

```
<?php
$dir = "img/";
$img = glob($dir . "*.jpg");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Photography</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <section class="imageCont">
        <?php foreach ($img as $image) {echo "<img src='$image' class='imageCont' style='max-width:200px' />";}?>
    </section>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
.imageCont img {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  margin: 1px;
}

.imageCont img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 47px -2px #000000bf;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.landscape {
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.portrait {
  max-height: 133px;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

JS

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
  $('.imageCont img').each(function () {
    if ($(this).width() / $(this).height() >= 1) {
      $(this).addClass('landscape');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('portrait');
    }
  });
});
```

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBsMD.jpg)

Comment: There's no need for that jQuery code and two classes; just set all images to `height: 133px`

Answer (score 0):

So making progress and i like this solution but the problem i have is that sometimes images do not load correctly. It's like they are stacked to one and another upon loading them.

[Sample error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eatuJ.jpg)

Currently the code looks like this:

```
HTML

<?php
$dir = "img/";
$img = glob($dir . "*.jpg");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Photography</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
        <?php foreach ($img as $image) {echo "<div class='grid-item'><img src='$image'></div>";}?>
    </div>

    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4/imagesloaded.pkgd.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal@4.0.5/dist/scrollreveal.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
  width: 33.333%;
}

.grid-item {
  float: left;
}

.grid-item img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}

.grid-item img:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px -1px #000000bf;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
```

JS

```
var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
  percentPosition: true,
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
  itemSelector: '.grid-item'
});

$grid.imagesLoaded().progress(function () {
  $grid.masonry();
});

ScrollReveal().reveal('.grid-item', {
  delay: 100,
});
```

Comment: When i disable ScrollReveal the issue goes away but i think the issue is a mix of using ScrollReveal and Masonry. I think the way the animation for masonry works it's not as fast loading and then ScrollReveal kick is before the Masonry loads, i'm only guessing.